# Incluir aquivo php com java

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo um suporte de token, como uma api com um token de acesso.
Só que não estou conseguindo ter o retorno das informações quando está em outro domínio.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal modal-fixed-footer show">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Aviso</h4>
        <p>Este Token é inválido.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect btn-flat" href="//license.fullprog.com/comprar">Comprar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  api();
 });
 function api(){
  $.get('http://license.fullprog.com/api/151519343520180105', function(resultadoplano){
   $('#body').html(resultadoplano);
  })
 }
</script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta tendo esse problema ao fazer a requisição ajax:

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same
>   Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   http://license.fullprog.com/api/151519343520180105. (Motivo: o
>   cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Basicamente, há um bloqueio quando se faz uma requisição ajax para um dominio diferente do qual o script está rodando. Para resolver esse problema você deve habilitar o acesso a partir de outros dominos na sua api. No [mozilla mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) tem alguns exemplos de como permitir, do mais simples ao mais completo.

Uma solução basica seria permitir o acesso para qualquer um, adicionando um header no topo de cada arquivo que pode ser acessado. Mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
//acesso a parti de qualquer dominio
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//acesso a partir de um dominio especifico
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dominio.com');
```

Isso deve resolver parte dos seus problemas. Para um controle mais completo você pode limitar quais métodos http estão aptos a acessar (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc). Na prática você só deveria retornar esses headers de controle de acesso quando, quando o navegador fizer uma requisição com o método **HTTP  OPTIONS**. Então você poderia fazer essa checagem assim (em todo arquivo, ou no seu front controller):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS") {
    //dominios permitidos, use * para permitir qualquer um
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dominio.com');
    //metodo http permitidos
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar o seguinte código na primeira linha da sua API:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Saiba mais em: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS